# Regular expression to truncate a String

Tags: java, regex

To truncate a String here is what I'm using :

```
String test1 = "this is test truncation 1.pdf";     
String p1 = test1.substring(0, 10) + "...";
System.out.println(p1);
```

The output is 'this is te...' 
How can I access the file name extension so that output becomes : 'this is te... pdf' 
I could use substring method to access the last three characters but other file extensions could be 4 chars in length such as .aspx

Is there a regular expression I can use so that "this is test truncation 1.pdf" becomes "this is te... pdf"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it all with a quick regex replace like this:

```
test1.replaceAll("(.{0,10}).*(\\..+)","$1...$2")
```

Comment: thanks, can you provide a quick explanation of this expression please ?

Comment: Sure, so you essentially gather two groups ($1 and $2) from the matching expression and replace them in the new one. `(.{0,10})` is the first group, "match whatever 0 to 10 times". The second group is `(\\..+)` which means "a dot followed by whatever at least once". The last part of the trick is to put `.*` in the middle, which is a greedy match, which will match as much as it can while still preserving the last group. So even if you have multiple dots in the middle of the name the `.*` will just eat them up.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use

```
test1.substring(0, 10) + "..." + test1.substring(test1.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this :

```
String[] parts = test1.split("\\.");
String ext = parts[parts.length-1];
String p1 = test1.substring(0, 10) + "..."+ext;
System.out.println(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple task you don't need Regex

```
String p1 = test1.substring(0, 10) + "..." + test1.substring(test1.lastIndexof('.'));
```

Comment: Per the question, extensions could be any length.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
String test1 = "this is test truncation 1.pdf";
String[] test2 = test1.split("\\.");     
String p1 = test1.substring(0, 10) + "..." + test2[test2.length-1];
System.out.println(p1);
```

Comment: What if more than one dots (.) are there?

Comment: change test2.[test2.length-1] to test2[test2.length-1]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.+[.](.*?)`

This matches all characters including dots, then a dot, then any character, but not greedy, so the first part should grab all of the string preceding the last dot. The capturing group will allow you to retrieve the part you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach but it will work only if u have single "." and that one too for file name extension.May be this one is a novice approach as u can use split method of String class too.......

```
    String str="abcdefg ghi.pdf";
    int dotIndex=str.indexOf(".")+1;
    if(str.indexOf(" ", dotIndex)!=-1)
        System.out.println(str.substring(dotIndex,str.indexOf(" ", dotIndex) ));
    else
    {
        System.out.println(str.substring(dotIndex,str.length() ));
    }
```